# I fetched an array and want to add it to my state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I fetched an array of objects but can't add (or replace) them to state.

```
const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'search',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
  getResults(state, action) {
     state = action.payload;
    },
   },
  });
```

I tried "state.push(action.payload)" but it turned out a nested array. "action.payload" is the right response.

Comment: state = [...state, action.payload] did not work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pushing it into the state creates a nested array,

For replacing, try

```
const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'search',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
  getResults(state, action) {
     return [...action.payload]; 
    },
   },
  });
```

For adding, try

```
const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'search',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
  getResults(state, action) {
     return [...state, ...action.payload];
    },
   },
  });
```

Comment: nah its not working. In getResults(state,actions) my IDE does not light up state when try anything with starting "state =".

Comment: I've updated my response to use a return statement like in normal reducers, please try that

Comment: well this works but I dont think this is the right thing to do.  
                                                                                                
                 action.payload.forEach(item => state.push(item));